# How to get all the View(UserControl) in the ViewModel using MVVM Light?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

I'm using MVVM Light and I don't know how to get all the View in ViewModel, if I use the arquitecture ViewModel => View is possible.

```cs
public MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        View = new AView();
    }

    public UIElement View { get; set; }
}

<UserControl x:Class="AView">
</UserControl>
```

But now I can't switch.

I want to export (EXCEL, PDF, etc) all the UserControl (View), now in MVVMLight I have View => ViewModel:

```
<UserControl
    DataContext={Binding MyViewModel, Source=StaticResource Locator} >
</UserControl>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `View` property in view code behind like this :

```cs
public MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get { return (this.DataContext as MyViewModel); } }
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += onLoaded;
    }
    void onLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.View = this;
    }
}
```